# NetHack Clients For OS X?

Tags: macos, nethack

What clients exist for OS X?

I am using the official QT port (graphical).

Comment: The definition of "best" is subjective depending on your preferences and needs, and therefore not suitable for this site. By changing your question to remove the subjective portion (i.e. "What is a nethack client for OS X which has [x] [y] and [z] features?") you could remove the subjective portion and the question would not risk being closed.

Comment: I changed it, can we re-open?

Comment: I find that once closed, re-opening a question is unlikely to happen. Just ask a new one.

Comment: Gotta love how people close subjective questions with subjective reasons >.<

Comment: @Jed: No, that's exactly what we don't want to happen. Don't do that.

Comment: The close votes on it right now seem to be left over from before. It says that I cast one of them but I definitely didn't after reopening.

Comment: @Mana Those are new close votes. When you have successfully closed a question and it gets reopened, you are forbidden from voting again. This is to prevent the system from just being a back-and-forth between the same pair of 5 users.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as off-topic, because I don't feel like it fits within the current guidelines of the site. It falls under software recommendation, which was deemed off-topic on the site a few years ago now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [nethack site (download links included)](http://www.nethack.org/v343/ports/download-mac.html):

```
Carbon Port
    OS: MacOS 8.1 or later, MacOS 9, MacOS X
    Map: text
    UI: GUI
    Notes:
    Replaces previous Mac "Classic" port.
    Compatible with save files from nethack-341.sit. 
MacOS X Tiles Port
    OS: MacOS X
    Map: Tiles (graphics)
    UI: GUI
    Notes:
    Also known as the "Mac Qt" port.
    Compatible with save files from current and prior Terminal ports (e.g., nethack-342-mac-term.pkg.sit, nethack-343-mac-term.pkg.sit). 
MacOS X Terminal Port
    OS: MacOS X
    Map: text
    UI: Terminal (or via telnet or ssh)
    Notes:
    Compatible with save files from prior Terminal ports (e.g., nethack-342-mac-term.pkg.sit) and current Qt and Terminal ports (nethack-343-2-macosx-qt.tgz, nethack-343-mac-term.pkg.sit).
```

Feel free to add on more clients you know, since this is community wiki.

Comment: Advice on configuring these clients would also be helpful. I have always found the tiles version listed here to be very ugly, and typically stick with the terminal version.

Answer (score 3):

There's always the good old `telnet nethack.alt.org` trick. You can share bones and scores with thousands(?) of other people.

Comment: If you have an Internet connection, this is always the preferred way to play because it saves your game on the server. Thus, you can resume your game on any computer you might come across.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new OSX client called nethack-cocoa that has a tiles mode and also an integrated ASCII mode.

Screenshots and links to the download can be found on the developer's blog: [NetHack-Cocoa](http://blog.dirkz.com/2010/03/nethack-343-ported-to-mac-os-x-cocoa.html)