# Is there a Nethack GUI client for OSX Lion?

Tags: nethack, macos

This should not be a dupe of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/nethack-clients-for-os-x).  I am trying to get Nethack up and running on OSX Lion, and the QT client no longer works (goodbye PPC support).

I found the [Nethack Cocoa project](http://code.google.com/p/nethack-cocoa/), however the tileset is both slow and not very attractive IMO (I was a fan of the smaller, quicker tileset).

My question is if there are any other non-PPC Nethack tile-based clients that **work** with Lion (other than the one I mentioned), and if not, any way to replace the existing tiles with the more standard Nethack tiles.

To be honest, if none exist I'll probably go back to the terminal...

Comment: Nethack Cocoa supports different tilesets in the Game > Tilesets menu item, including ascii mode. I'm not sure if any of these are "smaller, quicker" as you mention.

Comment: By quicker, I simply meant game speed (which also may be configurable...I haven't dug through it).  I would click the mouse to just quick move me to a staircase, and instead of zipping over there it would take its time to walk over.  Now that I think about it clearly that's probably just the game's programming.

Comment: @Nick: go ahead and turn that into an answer and I'll accept....I can get the tiles I like in that menu, and I suppose I'll just have to survive with the game mechanics as is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nethack Cocoa supports different (and custom) tilesets via the Game > Tilesets menu item. There's an ASCII mode as well but I'm not sure if it's any faster...

[image: Tile Set Menu in Nethack]

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the [runmode config option](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options#runmode).  The default for vanilla NetHack is "run", but it's possible that yours might be set to "walk" or "crawl".  If you want to maximize travel speed, set it to "teleport".

Answer (score 0):

One of the better gui clients is [vulture](http://www.darkarts.co.za/vulture), which works on intel macs fine.